# Неубывающая последовательность

Tags: python

Задана последовательность целых чисел(каждое число вводится на отдельной строке).Найти длинну самой длинной непрерывной неубывающей последовательности

Ввод:

2

4

1

5

7

9

10

3

Вывод: 4

(Максимальная последовательность 5 7 9 10)

Мой код выдает мне ошибку "string index out of range"

```
z=input()
vvod=[]
vvod.append(z)
nc=[]
while z!="":
    z=input()
    if z!="":
      vvod.append(z)
for i in range(len(vvod)):
  for x in vvod:
    if x<=x[i+1]:
      nc.append(i)
    else:
      nc.clear
print(len(nc))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вы забыли преобразовать введённые строки в числа.

Во-вторых, у вас будет `x` - это введённое число, а вы пытаетесь брать их него элементы `x[i+1]`. Ну и даже если это было бы нечто индексируемое, то был бы выход за границы, т.к. у вас цикл по всей длине.

В-третьих, `clear` - это функция, т.е. скобочки забыли.

В-четвёртых, вы нигде не сохраняете максимальную длину списка `nc`.

В общем, я думаю, что вы хотели написать что-то подобное:

```
print("Введите числа последовательности (или нажмите Enter чтобы завершить ввод)")
vvod = []
nc   = 1

z = input("Введите число : ")
while z != "":
    vvod.append(int(z))
    z = input("Введите число : ")

max_len = len(vvod)
if max_len > 1:
    max_len = 0

for i in range(len(vvod)-1):
    if vvod[i] <= vvod[i+1]:
        nc += 1
    else:
        nc = 1
    if nc > max_len:
        max_len = nc

print(max_len)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s, x, y, z = input(), -1, 0, 0
while s:
    if int(s) > x:
        y += 1
    else:
        z = max(z, y)
        y = 1
    x = int(s)
    s = input()
print(max(z, y))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]